# VBA ElseIf with multiple ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file with data in A - U and W - AA. I am trying to write code that will copy cells from the first range A - U and once it encounters a blank cell in A, it looks to the second range W - AA. The first part of the code is working, but I cannot seem to figure out how to call the second range.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long


    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Data")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("Audit")

    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("A1:A" & rowCount2)
    Set rng3 = shtSrc.Range("W1:W" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = 2

    For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then
            shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Value2
            shtDest.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value2
            shtDest.Range("G" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value2

            currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

            shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Value2
            shtDest.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 1)

            currentRow = currentRow + 1

        End If
    Next cell2

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `cell2.row` (row number of `cell2`) in conjunction with `rng3.Cells()`.

Comment: @RubberDuck , I dont understand where I would put that in the code. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I think you meant to ping @aucuparia.

Comment: @aucuparia , I dont understand where I would put that code. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: you still reference `cell2` in your `elseIf` statement; you need to reference the `rng3` cells

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the values in columns W:AA when the cell in column A is blank or do you want to start the loop over and start getting all of the values in the W:AA range?

Comment: @OpiesDad , Yes. I want to get the values in the cells W:AA when cells in column A are blank

Comment: @Jaycal - I am trying to say ElseIf cell2 is empty then look at ran3.cells and move that data over.

Comment: Do you need to be able to dynamically change rng3?  Or is this pretty set?

Comment: @OpiesDad , its set, it will be the same range of data each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the offset function to get to the appropriate columns:

```
Dim RangeDiff As Integer
...
Set rng2 = ...
Set rng3 = ...
RangeDiff = Rng3.Column - rng2.column
...

ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, RangeDiff).Value2
        shtDest.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, RangeDiff + 1)

...
```

EDIT per new understanding of requirements:

```
...
For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
    If cell2.Value <> "" Then
        shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Value2
        shtDest.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value2
        shtDest.Range("G" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value2

        currentRow = currentRow + 1

    ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        Exit For
    End If
Next cell2

For Each cell3 In rng3.Cells
    If cell3.Value <> "" Then
        shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = cell3.Value2
        shtDest.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2 = cell3.Offset(0, 1).Value2
        shtDest.Range("G" & currentRow).Value2 = cell3.Offset(0, 2).Value2

        currentRow = currentRow + 1

    ElseIf cell3.Value = "" Then

        Exit For
    End If
Next cell3
```

...

Comment: I added in your code, and its still not pulling over the next set of data in W. Any ideas?                                                Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim RangeDiff As Integer
    Dim currentRow As Long
    RangeDiff = rng3.Column - rng2.Column
    

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Data")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("Audit")

    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         
    
    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("A1:A" & rowCount2)
    Set rng3 = shtSrc.Range("W1:W" & rowCount2)

Comment: This code will get the values in cells W:AA for rows in which cell A is blank.  Are you intending on finding the first blank in column A and then starting over to get all the values in range 3/cells W:AA?

Comment: I am getting Run Time Error 91, object variable or with block not set  for the rangediff = rng3.Column - rng2.column string. I have googled and cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: My fault.  That line needs to be after you set the ranges.  I'll edit the answer to reflect.

Comment: Yes. When column A ends/ first blank cell, I need it to move to cell W and start to move that next data set over.

Comment: thanks that fixed the error message but it is still not moving the data set in range 3 over?

Comment: Exit Loop was giving a syntax error, if I remove it the code appears to work like I needed. Is the exit loop a needed piece of the code?

Comment: Not vital.  I put it in there to jump outside of the For Loop once an empty cell was encountered.  You could change it to "GoTo StartRange3" and then right before the next loop put "StartRange3:"

Comment: Change "Exit Loop" to "Exit For" and it should work, if this is what you actually want.